# $E[XYZ]=E[X]E[Y]E[Z]$, not independent but on the same probability space

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Given three random variables $X, Y, Z$ on the same probability
>   space $(Ω, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ such that $E(XYZ) = E(X)E(Y)E(Z)$. Show by counterexample that $X,Y,Z$ are not necessarily independent.

I've been having trouble finding an example of this on the same probability space. I was thinking of $X$~$N(0,1), Y=X^2, Z=X^3$. But in that case I assume these r.v. don't have the same probability space (their density functions are different). Could anyone give me a hint here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would you like to consider the following simple example?

$$\Omega = \{H,T\}$$
$$\mathcal{F} = 2^\Omega$$
$$P(\{H\}) = P(\{L\}) = 1/2$$
and
$$X = Y = Z$$ such that $X = 1$ if $H$ and $X=-1$ if $T$. 
Now you can verify that these random variables are dependent and the conditions regarding expectations still hold.

Comment: If I understood this example correctly we have that $E[XYZ]=E[X^3]=0=E[X]E[Y]E[Z], \mathbb{P}[X\cap Y\cap Z]=\mathbb{P}[X]\neq\mathbb{P}[X]\mathbb{P}[Y]\mathbb{P}[Z]=\mathbb{P}[X]^3$, so they must be dependent?

Comment: @Holograph You take expectations of _random variables_ (so "$E[X]$, $E[XYZ]$" make sense). You take probabilities of _events_ (so "$P[X]$, $P[Y]$" make no sense).

Comment: Another example would be to just take $X=0$ and define $Y$ and $Z$ as (almost) anything else.

Comment: You are right, thanks for noticing :). About the other example, if you take $Y$ and $Z$ as anything else, don't you get a different probability space?